# Check if a list matches loop

Tags: python

I have this code that checks if the numbers of list `listNum` are match the numbers of the loop

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    fileNum = [int(x.rstrip()) for x in lines]

listNum = list(range(1, 101))
yes = str(fileNum)
if yes == str(listNum):
    print("Matched!")
```

But there's no result, What is the problem?

Comment: Please show the content of your file

Comment: When in doubt, print stuff out: `print(str(fileNum))` and `print(str(listNum))`

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer `10
20
30
31`

Comment: You can compare lists directly... Why do you need `str()`?

Comment: try pdb https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html `python3 -m pdb myscript.py` .. `b` to set a breakpoint on the line you want and then you can inspect the running state

Comment: Umm... `10 20 30 31` doesn't match `range(1, 101)`, so what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't know if my method is correct or not, but I want every number in the `listNum` pass in the loop, and if there is a number in the `listNum` that matches a number in the file, it will print

Comment: Are you looking to test if your two unordered lists lists are identical or if the items in one list are all in the second list?

Comment: @JonSG Something like you have list `BMW,Volvo,Camry` of cars and you want to see if there is a car in the example file `BMW` that matches the car in the list, if yes then it print

Comment: `"BMW" in cars_list` would test that, not `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is checking if the string representations of boths lists are comparable, not subsets of the lists, or any individual elements

> if there is a number in the listNum that matches a number in the file, it will print

This will read a file into a list of numbers

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    numbers = [int(x.rstrip()) for x in f]
```

If you want to check if any number in a range exists in that list, use `any()`

```
if any(1 <= x < 101 for x in numbers):
    print("Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you all guys !!! Please last question, How do I know which number is matched in the file?

Answer (score 0):

From you description, it looks like you want to test what items in `listnum` are also in `filenum`. A simple comprehension will give you that:

```
fileNum = [12, 20, 30, 31, -1]
listNum = list(range(1, 101))

print([i for i in listNum if i in fileNum])
print(any(i for i in listNum if i in fileNum))
```

Gives:

```
[12, 20, 30, 31]
True
```

Depending on if duplicates are important or not, you can also intersect the sets like:

```
print(list(set(fileNum) & set(listNum)))
print(any(set(fileNum) & set(listNum)))
```

also results in:

```
[12, 20, 30, 31]
True
```